# City-themed Cryptic Clues

Tags: cryptic-clues

Below are several cryptic-crossword style clues, which all clue to cities in the world. Solve them!

> In England, puddle of bile? (9)
>
> He, president Arthur, is in England (10)
>
> Canadian Lemon-tar concoction (8)
>
> Heard short reformer in Europe (6)

Hint:

> For clue 4, short indicates a shortform of a word for "reformer"

Comment: Knowing that they're cities, it's too easy to separate the cryptic and definition parts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In England, puddle of bile? (9)

> **Liverpool** (liver = where the bile at; pool = puddle)

He, president Arthur, is in England (10)

> **Manchester** (he = man, Chester Arthur)

Canadian Lemon-tar concoction (8)

> **Montreal** (via @Hugh Meyers) - (M O N T R E A L mixed up is L E M O N T A R)

Heard short reformer in Europe (6)

> **Prague** - (sounds like *prog*, short for *progressive*)